# How to change only one parameter using vue router-link

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a user list component and also a calendar component. When I click on a user link I want the url to only change the selectedUser parameter but leave all other params alone.

Right now if I click on Change date link it changes the date but then if I click on user link it still sees the old date as it was rendered.

> url: /users/John/month/2019/01 after clicking on Change date -
>   /users/John/month/2009/09
>
> Then when I click on one of the users - /users/Bob/month/2019/01 <=
>   back to the old date

user link looks like this

```
<li v-for="user in users">
    <router-link
        :class="{ active: user.id == selected }"
        :to="{ name: 'MainRoute', params: { selectedUser: user.id }}">
        {{ user.username }}
    </router-link>
</li>
```

and calendar link for changing dates looks like this

```
<router-link
    :to="{ name: 'MainRoute', params: { selectedMonth: '09', selectedYear: '2009' }}">
    Change date
</router-link>
```

Here is my routes object

```
{
    name: 'MainRoute',
    path: '/users/:selectedUser/:selectedView/:selectedYear/:selectedMonth',
    ...
}
```

Comment: one solution would be to use localStorage - I could write an answer with that approach if that's an option for you?

Comment: yes, at this point I'm just desperate...

Comment: ok - gimme like 5 minutes to write the answer..

Comment: is F_Mekk's answer sufficient for you?

Comment: It might be, let me try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access actual route params by $route.params, so maybe you can use it like that :

```
  <li v-for="user in users">
    <router-link
    :class="{ active: user.id == selected }"
    :to="{ name: 'MainRoute', params: {selectedUser: user.id,
         selectedView :$route.params.selectedView,
         selectedMonth: $route.params.selectedMonth, 
         selectedYear: $route.params.selectedYear}}">
    {{ user.username }}
    </router-link>
  </li>
```

Comment: hmm I'm getting - TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

Comment: maybe try to remove the this like $route.params

Answer (score 1):

```
  <li v-for="user in users">
    <button @click="changeOnlyOneParam('selectedUser', user.id)">
      {{ user.username }}
    </button>
  </li>
```

changeOnlyOneParam method:

```
methods: {
    changeOnlyOneParam(paramName, changeTo) {
        let params = this.$route.params
        params[paramName] = changeTo
        this.$router.push({ name: this.$route.name, params: params })
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work when I tried it. Apparently, since the reference of `params` doesn't change, Vue Router ignores the push.  One has to do something like `let params = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$route.params))`.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you are not allowed to change the this.$route object. A copy is needed:

```
this.$router.push({ 
        name: this.$route.name,
        query: {...this.$route.query, [name]:value}
    });
```